# como filtrar valores repetidos no php o resultado de uma busca no banco de dados

Tags: php

Ola estou criando um sistema que me retorna do banco de dados varias datas, mas gostaria de apenas uma de cada sem as repetições, eu ja tentei com array_unique, mas sem sucesso, acho que deve ser pelo fato de minha pesquisa retornar em associação OBJ, se alguem puder me dar uma sugestão eu ficaria agradecido.

$sql_historico = "SELECT * FROM historico WHERE id_condominio = " .$id_condominio;
       $historico = $PDO->prepare( $sql_historico);

```
   $historico->execute();
   if($historico->rowCount()>0){
    while($valor_historico = $historico->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
     $historico_data = $valor_historico->data;
```

}
}

Comment: distinct não resolveria?

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de informa que consegui uma solução mais simples, eu utilizei um recurso do SQL que filtra e agrupa o resultado eliminado valores repetidos (GROUP BY +nome do campo da tabela que se deseja eliminar valores iguais.

Comment: Um `SELECT DISTINCT` também funciona: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp